# how to add rows in table in html <td></td>?

Tags: html

I'm new to html ,i need to add tags inside the table row but whenever i add tags it doesn't print values only empty fields are shown .here is sample value added in between .The row data is only tags.Can anyone help me with this

```html
<td>
  <parents>
    <proc pid="19344" parentPid="7084" path="C:\Program Files (x86)\COMODO\Comodo ITSM\RmmService.exe" cmdline="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\COMODO\Comodo ITSM\RmmService.exe&quot; 
    --run_procedure
    --in Global\sharedInputMemory_124 
    --out Global\sharedOutputMemory_125 
    --err Global\sharedErrorMemory_126" name="RmmService.exe" interpreter="false" sha1="0F3F5B4F23C03FC4BA72BE38A6E44DCD6EEB13C9" />
    <proc pid="7084" parentPid="1332" path="C:\Program Files (x86)\COMODO\Comodo ITSM\RmmService.exe" cmdline="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\COMODO\Comodo ITSM\RmmService.exe&quot;" name="RmmService.exe" interpreter="false" sha1="0F3F5B4F23C03FC4BA72BE38A6E44DCD6EEB13C9" />
    <proc pid="1332" parentPid="1252" path="C:\Windows\System32\services.exe" cmdline="" name="services.exe" interpreter="false" sha1="D7A213F3CFEE2A8A191769EB33847953BE51DE54" />
    <proc pid="1252" parentPid="0" path="C:\Windows\System32\wininit.exe" cmdline="" name="wininit.exe" interpreter="false" sha1="96B04445102445682879C8F21E38A93A30E8F3FD" />
  </parents>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you trying to print XML inside HTML table? HTML doesn't now what is `<parents>` and `<proc>`. You will have to escape those tags using `&lt;parents&gt;` and `&lt;proc&gt;` respectively.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your values are all tag attributes and the tags are not know HTML tags. Please tell us what your expected out it

Comment: all those tag values should be displayed in html table but when i simply use <td> those value are not visible in table ,it just show empty row in html instead of those tags